# How to supply many argv and outputredirection with one bash var?

Tags: bash, redirect

In file a.lst:

```
in1.a in1.b > out1.a 2> out1.b
in2.a in2.b > out2.a 2> out2.b
```

In do.sh:

```
CLI=$(sed -n -e "1 p" a.lst)
perl a.pl $CLI
```

I want to run like `perl a.pl in1.a in1.b > out1.a 2> out1.b`, how can I make it work ?

Comment: $ARGV is populated with every argument. What doesn't work is the outputredirection

Comment: Why don't you use `head -n 1` instead of `sed` if you just want the first line?

Comment: Well, there is an environment var for the line number.
I need to for each line in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it here, but it looks like using `eval` will work, so:

```
eval perl a.pl $CLI
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat a.lst | while read all
do
   eval perl a.pl $all
done
```

to evaluate the redirect part just add eval as posted by someone earlier

Comment: Your answer reads each line. The OP apparently only wants the first line (`sed "1 p"`). Also, if you are reading all the lines, instead of `cat|while`, you should use `done < a.lst`

Comment: This is a job script for Grid Engine Job Array, `#$ -t 1-10` and `SEED=$(sed -n -e "$SGE_TASK_ID p" $SEEDFILE)` just reads each of the 10 lines for `$SEEDFILE`.

Comment: `done < a.lst`, How to write a similar script to this answer from "Abu Aqil" ?  Seems `do echo $*;done<a.lst` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is in a consistent format (always the same number of parameters and the same kind of redirection), you might be able to do this:

```
CLI=($(head -n 1 a.lst))
perl a.pl "${CLI[0]}" "${CLI[1]}" > "${CLI[3]}" 2> "${CLI[5]}"
```

If you actually want to do this for each line in a.list:

```
while read -a CLI
do
    perl a.pl "${CLI[0]}" "${CLI[1]}" > "${CLI[3]}" 2> "${CLI[5]}"
done < a.lst
```

If you want just the first 10 lines of your input file, the last line can be changed to:

```
done < <(head -n 10 a.lst)
```